# how do I filter my recordset by 2 categories

Tags: php, mysql

How do I filter the following recordset by say 2 categories?

```
SELECT *
FROM newsevents
WHERE category = 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `IN` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM newsevents
WHERE category IN (1, 2)
```